# Creating edit function in the same controller laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

So I have a create function in my controller as shown below and my routes is as such, my question is is there a way for me to put a condition to different create and edit in the same function as both have quite similar coding. Can someone enlighten me pls?

```
class ManageAccountsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $users = User::orderBy('name')->get();
        $roles = Role::all();

        return view('manage_accounts', compact('users', 'roles'));
    }

    public function update()
    {
            // process the form here

    // create the validation rules ------------------------
        $rules = array(
        'name'             => 'required',                        // just a normal required validation
        'email'            => 'required|email|unique:users',     // required and must be unique in the user table
        'password'         => 'required|min:8|alpha_num',
        'password_confirm' => 'required|same:password',           // required and has to match the password field
        'mobile'           => 'required', 
        'role_id'          => 'required'
        );

    // do the validation ----------------------------------
    // validate against the inputs from our form
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // check if the validator failed -----------------------
        if ($validator->fails()) {

        // redirect our user back to the form with the errors from the validator

            $input = Input::except('password', 'password_confirm');

            $input['autoOpenModal'] = 'true'; //Add the auto open indicator flag as an input.
            return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withInput($input)
            ->withErrors($validator);

        } else {
        // validation successful ---------------------------

        // user has passed all tests!
        // let user enter the database

        // create the data for our user
            $user = new User;
            $user->name     = Input::get('name');
            $user->email    = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->mobile   = Input::get('mobile');
            $user->role_id  = Input::get('role_id');

        // save our user
            $user->save();

        // redirect ----------------------------------------
        // redirect our user back to the form so they can do it all over again
            Session::flash('flash_message', 'User successfully added!');

            return redirect()->back();

        }
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('manage_accounts', 'ManageAccountsController@index');
Route::post('manage_accounts', 'ManageAccountsController@update');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try moving some of this code out of your controller. If you were to use Repositories, then you would be able to encapsulate some of your logic in order to use it for both functions.

Also you can handle all this validation without writing all the extra code into your controller - see http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation.

This may all seem a bit overkill at first, but once you get the hang of it, your code will be much more manageable and extendable.

(for more on these I would thoroughly recommend Jeffery Way's Laracasts https://laracasts.com/ - this helped me a lot when I was learning Laravel)

```
//  routes.php

// http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers
Route::resource('manage_accounts', 'ManageAccountsController');


// ManageAccountsController.php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class ManageAccountsController extends Controller
{

    public $userRepository;


    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function index() {

        $users = User::orderBy('name')->get();
        $roles = Role::all();
        return view('manage_accounts', compact('users', 'roles'));
    }

    public function store(StoreUserRequest $request)
    {
      // validation already handled using this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation
        $this->userRepository->upsert($request)

        Session::flash('flash_message', 'User successfully added!');

        return redirect()->back();

    }

    public function update(StoreUserRequest $request, $id)
    {
        // validation already handled using this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation
        $this->userRepository->upsert($request, $id)

        Session::flash('flash_message', 'User successfully updated!');

        return redirect()->back();

    }
}


// UserRepository.php
class UserRepository {



    public function upsert($data, $id = null)
    {

            // You will also need something like this
            if(isset($data['id']))
            {
                $user = $this->user->find($data['id']);
            }
            else {
                $user = new User;
            }


            $user->name     = $data['name'];
            $user->email    = $data['email'];
            $user->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
            $user->mobile   = $data['mobile'];
            $user->role_id  = $data['role_id'];

            // save our user
            $user->save();

            return $user;
        }
    }

}
```

Please use the code here as a guide (I have written this in a hurry and it will certainly contain errors). Have a quick read up on repositories and I think it should all make sense.

The basic premise here is to separate out code that you want to re-use rather than squashing it all into the same function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: First of all, thanks so much. Code do seem more organised. Mange to get my create operation working, now I'm wondering how do I call the update operation. In my route I specify 

Route::post('manage_accounts', 'ManageAccountsController@register');

which is used for the calling the create method, how abt update? Can I just specify it like this after the register route, 

Route::post('manage_accounts', 'ManageAccountsController@update');

Comment: Also yoou wrote above UpdateUserRequest $request, does this mean I have to create another validation request file for the update? So if there was a delete method, since the validation my be diff, I would have create another request file am I right?

Comment: Good questions. So, I missed a couple of things here, but have edited the post to make this all a bit more complete. You could make good use of Laravel's 'restful resource controllers' to tidy up your routes and keep you thinking and coding RESTfully (good practise)

Consider also adding the code in your index method to the repository - then your Controller can do its job as a mediator and not have to deal with logic which you might want to reuse again later.

Comment: Perhaps using a method like 'getAll()' in your user repository which does User::orderBy('name')->get(). Then create a separate repository for Roles (RolesRepository). This will keep your code more in line with Object orientated code principles (Have a read about the single responsibility principle here - https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design).

Comment: As for the form validation - I believe this works via type-hinted dependency injection, so basically you can just use the same validation for both and then inject the same validation class (Laravel searches for the class that you have type-hinted and pulls it into your method)

I have edited the code above with StoreUserRequest to demonstrate this.

Comment: In the UserRepository, you set $id = null, wont that causes the $id to always be null hence always creating new user?

Comment: Not if you pass a variable to it. It will only be null if nothing is passed. So, your update method will pass through an id and your create method wont pass anything (and it will be set as null).

Comment: Thanks so much! If I were to use modal-dialog, how do I pass the id to the controller?

Comment: You would have to use the correct route. So instead of posting to /manage_accounts you would post to /manage_accounts/{$id}. Then the id will be picked up in the controller as the $id variable. (Be sure to use a POST request). 

Perhaps if we start talking about routing and the necessary front-end calls, we should start a new question about that, as this is going to get a bit lengthy? We should also consolidate the above to make sure it's helpful for anyone else reading this.

Comment: Okay okay, I've actually posted a new question on it, not sure whether what I posted is relevant. Thanks so much for your time though. =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464264/passing-id-from-view-using-modal-dialog-to-controler

Comment: Okay perfect. Not at all, hope this has been useful. If we are okay on this one for now, would you be able to set as answered? 
I'll try to pick this up on your new question.

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE OR CREATE***

Try the ***updateOrCreate()*** in Eloquent to create or update a record matching the attributes.

Read API docs [udateOrCreate()](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_updateOrCreate)

Your code will be like:

```
Model::updateOrCreate( ['id' => $id], ['firstField' => 'value', 'secondField' => 'value'] );
```

Note: first parameter is the match to be found and second the data's to be saved.

Hope this is helpful.