# Passing id from view using modal-dialog to controler

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, modal-dialog

I'm using the bootstrap modal to create and update users. I manage to get the create function working but not the update. My controller works as such that if no $user->id variable is passed it will create a new user else if there is an $user->id it will update that instead. However I cant figure how to pass the $user->id to the controller as I'm using a modal dialog. Can someone help me with this? My code can be seen as below.

routes.php

```
Route::resource('manage_accounts', 'ManageAccountsController');
```

manage.blade.php

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="button"
      data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form">Edit&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form">Register New User</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="form" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">User Information</h4>

...
```

controller.php

```
class ManageAccountsController extends Controller
{
    public $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function index() 
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('name')->get();
        $roles = Role::all();

        return view('manage_accounts', compact('users', 'roles'));
    }

     public function store(StoreUserRequest $request)
    {
      // validation already handled using this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation
        $this->userRepository->upsert($request);

        Session::flash('flash_message', 'User successfully added!');

        return redirect()->back();

    }

    public function update(StoreUserRequest $request, $id)
    {
        // validation already handled using this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation
        $this->userRepository->upsert($request, $id);

        Session::flash('flash_message', 'User successfully updated!');

        return redirect()->back();

    }
}

class UserRepository {

    public function upsert($data, $id = null)
    {

            // You will also need something like this
            if(isset($data['id']))
            {
                $user = $this->user->find($data['id']);
            }
            else {
                $user = new User;
            }

            $user->name     = $data['name'];
            $user->email    = $data['email'];
            $user->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
            $user->mobile   = $data['mobile'];
            $user->role_id  = $data['role_id'];

            // save our user
            $user->save();

            return $user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are using AJAX? Aren't you?

Comment: Lets say that the id of your user is 1, then you will need to ensure that the AJAX request is setup to PUT/PATCH to:  /manage_accounts/1 - see here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers under 'Actions Handled By Resource Controller'.

Comment: Sorry, I dont really get what you mean, I undertand the part on the resource controller but the request to setup part, can you explain a little further. Sorry I'm actually quite new to laravel and its framework.

Comment: That's okay. I think this is more of a javascript question now, so don't worry about Laravel at this point. Just know that you need to be posting to this: /manage_accounts/$id

Can you show the code that you used to successfully create a user?

Comment: I think I'm kind of getting it. Anyway here's part of the code.

<div class="modal-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/manage_accounts" novalidate>
                   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name">Username:</label>                  
...

 You're looking for this, <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/manage_accounts" novalidate>, am I right?

Comment: Since this method="post, I ahve to add a method="PUT/PATCH", something along this line, am I right?

Comment: :) looking good. Put the method as "PUT",  and change action to action="/manage_accounts/{{ $userId }}". Then you just need to pass through the userId to the view

Comment: So I had to change my route to 

Route::resource('manage_accounts', 'ManageAccountsController',
                ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'update']]); 

and did as you said, but when I try edit it shows me a MethodNotAllowedHttpException error, where did I go wrong?

Comment: This is what I wrote, <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="PUT" action="/manage_accounts/{{ $user->id }}" novalidate>

Comment: My fault. Change the method back to method="POST" and add _method="PUT" - I don't think HTML forms allow PUT requests, so we have tell Laravel separately http://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-i-can-not-get-inputs-from-a-putpatch-request

Comment: So I manage to get the PUT method,   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/manage_accounts/{{ $user->id }}" novalidate>
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">, unfortunately now my store method would not work. Is there any way or I have to create two modal, one for store and the other for update.